# Is this set of integrals verified by infinitely many functions?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, probability-distributions

We have two bounded continuous functions $f_{1}(x,y)$ and $f_{2}(x,y)$, defined on $\mathcal{A}=[a,b]\times [c,d]$ and $\mathcal{B}=[e,f]\times [g,h]$ respectively, with no intersection between both sets. In addition, $f_{1}(x,y)$ and $f_{2}(x,y)$. Ley $r$ and $s$ be positive constants, $x'$ and $y'$ are variables that verify $x'>a$ and $y'<f$. Let $f_{1}(x)=\int_{c}^{d}f_{1}(x,y)dy$ and $f_{2}(y)=\int_{e}^{f}f_{2}(x,y)dx$. The functions verify the following integrals:
$$\int_{\mathcal{A}}f_{1}(x,y)dx dy=r$$
$$\int_{\mathcal{B}}f_{2}(x,y)dx dy=\frac{r}{s}$$
$$\int_{a}^{x'}f_{1}(x)\leq s\cdot \int_{y'}^{h}f_{2}(y)$$

Then, could we say that there are infinitely many functions $f_{1}(x,y)$ and $f_{2}(x,y)$ that verify these equations. I do not need a proof for this, I just want to confirm my intuition

Comment: Sorry, I misstated the conditions.@J.G. How could I show the infinitude of solutions taking a linear combination of both functions?

Answer (score 1):

We seek solutions of$$\int_{[a,\,b]\times[c,\,d]}f_1dxdy=\int_{[e,\,f]\times[g,\,h]}sf_2dxdy=r,\,\int_{[a,\,x^\prime]\times[c,\,d]}f_1dxdy\le\int_{[e,\,f]\times[y^\prime,\,h]}sf_2dxdy.$$One solution in terms of [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) is $f_1=\frac{r[x\le x^\prime]}{(x^\prime-a)(d-c)},\,sf_2=\frac{r[y\ge y^\prime]}{(f-e)(h-y^\prime)}$, for which the last condition's $\le$ becomes $=$, with both sides $r$. Call this solution $f_1=f_{10},\,f_2=f_{20}$, so an arbitrary solution with $g_1:=f_1-f_{10},\,g_2:=f_2-f_{20}$ is equivalent to$$\int_{[a,\,b]\times[c,\,d]}g_1dxdy=\int_{[e,\,f]\times[g,\,h]}sg_2dxdy=0,\,\int_{[a,\,x^\prime]\times[c,\,d]}g_1dxdy\le\int_{[e,\,f]\times[y^\prime,\,h]}sg_2dxdy.$$If we can find nonvanishing $g_1,\,g_2$ satisfying this, we can rescale them by any common factor, so we're done. One choice is$$g_1=(2y-c-d)f_1,\,g_2=(2x-e-f)f_2.$$(Again, the $\le$ becomes $=$ in this case, with both sides $0$.)